# Bumps in secondary coil

Tags: coil, tesla-coil, secondary-winding

[image]

I am making my first Tesla coil, and I need some advice on the secondary coil.

I have some bumps present and I don't know how to remove them from the wire.

Do I need the wires to be straightened and if so, how?

They are covered in enamel, so I would also like to not remove the covering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those kinks in the wire are ok and won't prevent the Tesla coil from working so long as you have the appropriate number of windings.  You will lose some of your space efficiency so the performance of the coil will drop some.  I would be more concerned with breaking the fragile enamel while trying to straighten the wire.   Be sure the remaining wire is straight before you wrap it around your coil.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for the response. Quick question, when turning it , would the force of my hand pushing down on the wire hard , to try and keep it straight, remove the enamel

Comment: That's something you'll have to find out through experimentation.  You would see flaking enamel and a color change where the copper wire is exposed.  If you don't see any flakes and the wire color is consistent then you should be good to go.